# I need some help trying to sort a list of strings but at a particular index on that list

Tags: python, list, algorithm, sorting

I would appreciate some help with a python piece of code im having issues with.

I have a list which contains strings. Here is a snippet of the list. It is a lot longer though.

```
[['AAPL', '1d', '58.82', '155.04'], ['MSFT', '1d', '63.16', '118.6']]
```

What i am trying to do is to sort the list at index 3 (so the values '155.04' , '118.6' etc). I have tried the following, which doesn't work since i have floats as string i presume.

```
sorted(list, key=itemgetter(3), reverse=True)
```

I've looked into using sort() and sorted() but i cant seem to find a way to both sort ints as strings and also at a particular index.There are no error messages, its just not in the correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `lambda` to convert to `float` just for the comparison

```
values = [['AAPL', '1d', '58.82', '155.04'], ['MSFT', '1d', '63.16', '118.6']]
values = sorted(values, key=lambda x:float(x[3]), reverse=True)
# values stays the same the data is already reverse sorted by the 4th value
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Your sort-key has to convert the last element of each sublist to a float.

```
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda sublist: float(sublist[-1]), reverse=True)
[['AAPL', '1d', '58.82', '155.04'], ['MSFT', '1d', '63.16', '118.6']]
```

You could write that `lambda` function as a non-anonymous function for readability

```
def last_as_float(lst):
    return float(lst[-1])
```

and then pass `key=last_as_float`.